# Converting data collected at political units (eg. census tract) to new ecologically-defined units (eg. watershed)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.5, watershed, health

I have socioeconomic status (SES) data of every health authority (HA) in the province. I overlay a watershed boundary polygon on top of multiple HAs and would like to know: What is the SES of the population residing within the watershed?

I am using ArcGIS desktop 10.5. So far I have tried converting HAs to points and then rasterizing it so that I can use the zonal statistics tool to summarize all cells within the watershed. However, this does not account for the fact that people are not homogeneously distributed in space and there is no way of knowing how accurate the conversion was (this is where I am stuck).

Comment: For clarification, you are trying to aggregate your socioeconomic data from one areal unit (e.g., HA, presuming these are polygons) to another (e.g., watershed), right? Without knowing the granularity of your HAs (average number of HAs within the watershed), it is a bit hard to say. In any case, I think, you have an aggregate of SES attributes (presumed homogeneity across your areal units) and it will be again homogeneous once you aggregate them to something larger. If you carry on working with vector data, I suggest using Union tool followed by area weighted average calculation for SESs.

Comment: I would use Union too.  You could use the shape area to redistribute data from one layer to the other if you are happy to accept an assumption that the data is distributed evenly.

Comment: I think that you should include a picture that illustrates what you are trying to do.